# How to read excel line by line in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, selenium

I want to ask how can How to read excel line by line in pandas. I want it to be in a loop that will get line by line information for facebook login with selenium. Hope everyone is easygoing because I'm a newbie

```
import pandas as pd

pd.options.display.max_rows = 28
data = pd.read_excel(r'file.xlsx')

#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
username = pd.DataFrame(f1,columns=['Name'])
password = pd.DataFrame(f1,columns=['Pass'])

for i in df:
    print('Current row:', i)
```

Comment: As an aside, `pd.read_excel` returns a dataframe, so `data` is already the thing you want. You don't need to re-dataframe it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since you're new to programming, a good counsel I can give is to read and search the documentation when doubts first appear.
Many tools even have tutorials to help you start coding and search to help you find basic code.
Check this link, I think it will help a lot!
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/02_read_write.html?highlight=read%20excel

Comment: It is always helpful to cite documentation: it's both informative for the question at hand but also as a soft nudge to do what you're referring to. This doesn't answer the question that was posed though.  It isn't just reading an excel document with pandas, but doing so line by line.  This could be important for those who want to iterate with chunks of a file rather than loading the entirety of the file's contents (which may not be possible).

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that you read your Excel file line-by-line? Or is it also okay for you to read the entirety of your Excel file into a Dataframe and just iterate through that?